# How can mathematical models be applied to image analysis

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, image-processing

I'm quite interested in how mathematical models can be used in analysing images. For example, I'm aware that mixed effect models can be using in image analysis but I was just wondering if there are any other branches of mathematics that lend themselves to image analysis? I know about Fourier transforms too in image analysis. I hope the question isn't too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Linear algebra
- Functional analysis
- Convex analysis / optimization
- Statistics
- Morphological analysis
- etc., etc.

You can take a tour on Gabriel Peyre's [Numerical tours](http://www.numerical-tours.com/), and see how these branches are beautifully inter-woven.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to work in digital framework, i think topics like compressed sensing is state-of-art which can be supported by optimization problems.

Answer (score 1):

Google these terms: 
Wavelets
Curvelets
Mumford-Shah
Deblurring
Deconvolution